# Initial Pageload Delay while connecting to Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

My code was working perfect until recently. Right now the initial connection just to open www.google.com takes something like 25 seconds. All this while the screen is stuck at the point shown below. 
Once the page loads then everything else else works all fine (clicks, selections, going to a different url etc).

The code I use is

```
IWebDriver driver = InitiateWebDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.in");
```

[image: Page load delay]

Comment: Update the chromedriver version to the latest version and see if it helps. May be your browser got updated

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, I did try that.. Wasnt of much help though.